# Symfony 6 : Customize a form with radio buttons

Tags: symfony, radio-button, symfony-forms

I have a form and want to customize it with symfony :

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="auto" onClick="getMarques('auto')" id="check1">
<label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="check1"><span class="m-circle"></span></label>
<label class="s-submitCheck" for="check1">Auto</label>
```

I have tried this:

```
{% for child in formAnnonce.category %}
 
 {{ form_widget(child, {'attr' : {'class': 'form-check-input'}, {'name': 'type'}, {'id': 'check1'} }) }}
        {{ form_label(child)}}
        {{ form_help(child) }}
        {{ form_errors(child) }}



{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So what did you expect, what was the result, how did it not meet your expectations?

Comment: Hi Klaus Gütter, i had resolved it finaly. Thanks.

Comment: If it may be useful for others, consider posting your solution as answer. If not, consider deleting the question.

Comment: If this is meant to provide the solution, add it as answer, not as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for child in formAnnonce.category %} 
   {{ form_widget(child, {'attr': {'onclick': 'getMarques("' ~ child.vars.value~'")'}})}}
   <label class="s-submitCheckLabel" for="{{ child.vars.id }}"><span class="m-circle"> </span></label> 
   <label class="s-submitCheck" for="{{ child.vars.id }}">{{ child.vars.label </label> 
{% endfor %}
```